# How to disable Database Update Alerts in the Backend in Bolt 3.4.8 CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

Hello Community and Developers,

I have a problem in the backend of the Bolt 3.4.8 CMS. This is the new version.

Even if the database is being updated, the update message will always be visible in the backend. How can I disable it?

It annoys a bit that this message in pink color can be seen again and again.

Can I disable the message via the config.yml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug with some database upgrades where some changes were not correctly detected. This is supposed to be fixed in version 3.5.6 - so you should be able to get rid of that message by upgrading to a newer version of bolt: https://github.com/bolt/bolt/releases/tag/v3.5.6

Comment: Thanks for the Hints. I make a upgrade to Bolt 3.5.7 and waiting for Bolt 3.6.0 :-)

Answer (score -1):

It's can't disable via config.yml. I would not recommend disable it. Even if you disable this, you will not see suggestions for other updates when it's will need.

What fields does it offer you to update?
I had such a problem with the "User profiles" extension, the field "description". I did not find a solution, just deleted this field, because I did not use it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: paper1111, I didn't quite understand the essence of your comment. I wrote that I had the same problem and my solution for it. I don't have any questions.